# Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\UndefinedOptionsException: The options " " do not exist. Known options are: ""

Tags: forms, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit, symfony-forms

This is my form

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class JoseType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nombre')
            ->add('apellido','entity', array(
                    // 'required'    => false,
                    'empty_value' => 'Select',
                    'mapped'      => false,
                    'class'       => 'AppBundle:SolutionTypeCategory',
                    'attr'        => array(
                                        'placeholder' => 'Select',
                                        'data-msg-required' => "Required Solution Type Category",
                                        ),
                ))
            ->add('edad')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Jose'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_jose';
    }
}
```

I receive this error

> Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\UndefinedOptionsException: The options "attr", "class", "empty_value", "mapp
>   ed" do not exist. Known options are: "".

And the following is my test:

```
class ProjectTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    public function testJose()
    {
        $type = new JoseType();
        $form = $this->factory->create($type);        
    }

    // get extensions...
    protected function getExtensions()
    {
        $mockEntityType = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $mockEntityType->expects($this->any())->method('getName')
                       ->will($this->returnValue('entity'));

        return array(new PreloadedExtension(array(
                $mockEntityType->getName() => $mockEntityType,
        ), array()));
    }

}
```

I don't understand that error, looking take the values array options of form. 
Why?

Help me please!

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.6.13 version

Comment: `empty_value` should be `placeholder`. see: http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: no only is `empty_value`, also is `attr` and `mapped` attributes , moreover if it were bad setup, symfony would return an error, already changed `empty_value` to `placeholder`, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke ->add() from $builder - there is a list of pre set options that you are allowed to use.

Each form type has a number of options to configure it, as explained in the [Symfony form types reference](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/reference/forms/types.html).